# Do i need to remove brackets for tokenization? RegexpTokenizer

Tags: python, tokenize

First attempt at tokenization using nltk's RegexpTokenizer for an assignment (necessary). Not sure if I should remove brackets?

> You are required to extract the token and append them into the list 'token'

...not sure if I even did this right.

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.probability import *
from itertools import chain
from tqdm import tqdm
import codecs
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
nltk.download('stopwords')

df_text = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\JobPostings.csv")

lower = []
for item in df_text['job_description']:
    lower = [item]
    lower.append(item.lower())

tokenizer_test = RegexpTokenizer(r"\s+", gaps=True)
tokens_test = tokenizer_test.tokenize(item)

token = [tokens_test]
print(token)
```

Output is:

[['Data', 'Scientist,', '(Staff', 'or', 'Principal)', 'at', 'realtor.com', '(View', 'all', 'jobs)', 'Santa', 'Clara,', 'CA', 'At', 'realtor.com,', 'we', 'process', 'terabytes', 'of', 'data', 'every', 'day', 'and', 'transform', 'that', 'data', 'into', 'information', 'that', 'powers', 'decisions', 'for', 'millions', 'of', 'homebuyers,', 'renters,', 'dreamers,', 'and', 'real', 'estate', 'professionals.', 'We', 'aim', 'to', 'radically', 'simplify', 'home', 'buying/selling', 'and', 'help', 'more', 'people', 'achieve', 'the', 'American', 'dream', 'on', 'our', 'realtor.com', 'website', 'and', 'mobile', 'apps.', 'We', 'seek', 'a', 'highly', 'seasoned', 'Data', 'Scientist', 'to', 'join', 'our', 'data', 'science', 'program', 'and', 'help', 'develop', 'it', 'to', 'its', 'full', 'potential.', 'As', 'a', 'key', 'member', 'of', 'the', 'data', 'science', 'team,', 'you', 'will', 'be', 'responsible', 'for', 'the', 'development', 'of', 'innovative', 'concepts,', 'research,', 'predictive', 'modeling,', 'and', 'machine', 'learning', 'algorithms.', 'Responsibilities:', 'Perform', 'exploratory', 'analysis', 'on', "realtor.com's", 'wealth', 'of', 'data', 'including', 'consumer', 'web', 'and', 'mobile', 'behavior', 'and', 'North', 'America’s', 'most', 'comprehensive', 'and', 'up-to-date', 'listings', 'and', 'properties', 'data', 'set.', 'Effectively', 'partner', 'with', 'product', 'and', 'engineering', 'teams', 'to', 'build', 'new', 'data-driven', 'and', 'machine', 'learning-based', 'features', 'in', 'our', 'professional', 'software', 'and', 'lead', 'monetization', 'products', 'to', 'enable', 'real', 'state', 'professionals', 'to', 'be', 'more', 'productive', 'and', 'effective', 'in', 'serving', 'the', 'needs', 'of', 'home', 'shoppers.', 'Help', 'improve', 'the', 'scope', 'our', 'data', 'sets', 'by', 'identifying', 'new', 'data', 'collection', 'and', 'procurement', 'opportunities', 'on', 'an', 'ongoing', 'basis', 'Drive', 'A/B,', 'multivariate', 'tests', 'and', 'design', 'of', 'experiments', 'to', 'facilitate', 'testing', 'of', 'new', 'product', 'and', 'design', 'features,', 'with', 'a', 'focus', 'on', 'improving', 'engagement,', 'retention,', 'and', 'conversion.', 'Select,', 'apply,', 'and', 'tune', 'a', 'diverse', 'set', 'of', 'tools', 'to', 'coherently', 'solve', 'challenging', 'business', 'goals', 'Create', 'automated', 'learning', 'systems', 'that', 'gracefully', 'scale', 'to', 'increasing', 'complexity', 'and', 'expectation', 'Develop', 'predictive,', 'explanatory', 'models', 'and', 'machine', 'learning', 'algorithms', 'Generate', 'descriptive', 'visualizations', 'and', 'presentations', 'to', 'communicate', 'insights', 'Mentor', 'a', 'team', 'of', 'data', 'scientists', 'on', 'data', 'exploration,', 'machine', 'learning', 'and', 'developing', 'data-based', 'products', 'Work', 'with', 'a', 'sense', 'of', 'ownership', 'and', 'urgency,', 'advocate', 'for', 'experimentation', 'based,', 'agile', 'culture.', 'Requirements:', 'MS', 'or', 'Ph.D.', 'in', 'statistics,', 'mathematics,', 'operations', 'research,', 'computer', 'science,', 'quantitative', 'analysis,', 'economics', 'or', 'related', 'field', 'is', 'required.', '7+', 'years', 'of', 'relevant', 'experience', 'in', 'data', 'science,', 'data', 'analytics,', 'or', 'applied', 'statistics,', 'Experience', 'with', 'machine', 'learning,', 'NLP,', 'data', 'mining,', 'statistical', 'modeling', 'tools,', 'and', 'underlying', 'algorithms', 'Experienced', 'in', 'R,', 'Perl,', 'Python,', 'Spark,', 'or', 'other', 'languages', 'and', 'frameworks', 'appropriate', 'for', 'large', 'scale', 'analysis', 'of', 'numerical,', 'textual,', 'image,', 'and', 'video', 'data', 'Strong', 'skills', 'in', 'data', 'gathering,', 'massaging', 'and', 'featurization', 'Working', 'experience', 'with', 'relational', 'databases', 'and', 'SQL', 'Experience', 'with', 'experiment', 'design', 'and', 'A/B', 'and', 'multivariate', 'tests', 'Experience', 'and', 'proven', 'track', 'record', 'developing', 'online', 'data', 'products', 'Strong', 'creative', 'thinking', 'and', 'problem-solving', 'skills', 'Excellent', 'oral', 'and', 'written', 'communication', 'and', 'presentation', 'skills']]

edit:
tried this out instead... thoughts?

```
df_text_jd = df_text.job_description

lower = []
for item in df_text_jd:
    lower.append(item.lower().replace('(','').replace(')',''))

l = []  
for token in item:
    tokenizer_test = RegexpTokenizer(r'\s+', gaps=True)
    token = tokenizer_test.tokenize(item)

    l.append(token)

l
```

Comment: Yeah, the extra brackets are probably unnecessary, (`tokens_test` is already a list of tokens), although I suppose it ultimately depends on what you want to do next.

Comment: You may also want to tokenize by more than just spaces, being that the tokens `(Staff`, `Staff` and `staff` don't really have different meanings. There are a variety of nltk functions that do this for you, or, if you really wanted to put in the work, you could make a more complicated regex

Comment: @bug_spray thank you for your feedback, I will try to comprehend this and fix it... I need to extract the token and append them into the list 'token' but have 0 idea how to do this and I just keep going in circles haha. Will try my best!

Comment: Change the name of `tokens_test` to `token`. Problem solved

Comment: @bug_spray thanks heaps! One question though if you don't mind, when I put the print statement within the for loop (print lower), the amount of words from the dataframe column is like 10000x times more (not exaggerating, there is supposed to be a word frequency of over 6000. Does tokenization remove duplication or did I do the wrong thing somewhere?

Comment: Tokenization doesn't remove duplicates, as you can see from the number of 'and' tokens.  You should remove the line that says `lower = [item]`. That line overwrites the list `lower` every iteration of the loop

Comment: @bug_spray ahhh right, idk how i didn't pick that up (I'm functioning on like 3 hours of sleep).. Still kinda at a loss as to why my code is only printing a small amount of words from the overall list (it crashes my computer temporarily when it tries to process all of the words). Should i consider running my tokenizer inside the for-loop or maybe create a nested loop to put all of that into another list?

Comment: If your dataframe is massive and NLTK doesn't work, you may want to consider checking out the Keras tokenizer in Tensorflow. From my experience it works faster on huge datasets, although it might not provide as much flexibility as NLTK

Comment: Don't use nested loops. You could put the tokenizer directly in the for loop (a good idea), or if you wanted you could add another column to your dataframe and just tokenize everything with something like `df_text["tokens"] = df_text["job_description"].apply(lambda s: tokenizer.tokenize(s))`

Comment: Will keep that in mind; thanks for the recommendations and help with all this - as you can see I'm very new to this stuff haha. I believe my assessment requires me to use NLTK (no idea why) and the dataframe is huge. Not sure how i'll go with this question haha, i tried doing the next one where the word frequency is meant to be over 6000 and my most common word was like..25 times *shrug*

Comment: @bug_spray just put the tokenizer in the for loop and it does exactly what i need when the print statement is within the for loop - once I put it outside of that, it drastically changes the results (i assume because it isn't iterating through each line of the df). Thanks for the suggestion - now to work out how to get the same result either printing outside the loop or by appending the tokenized list to another list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the brackets by modifying  the line where you append the lower case item to lower list:

```
lower.append(item.lower().replace('(','').replace(')',''))
```